# How do I get my files back from my desktop?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, filesystems

First I changed the downloads location to the desktop.
And then, in the desktop I made a file called "downloadsss"
Then I changed the downloads location to "downloadsss" and agreed to move all the files there.
Then my entire desktop was gone.
Am I done? Is my desktop gone forever? How do I get all my files back?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note: you wrote `downloadsss` (3 `s`), but in the picture it says `downloadssss` (4 `s`).

Comment: This is why backups should be regular and automatic, rather than made only when you expect something bad to happen.

Comment: Open a **PowerShell** window to `C:\Users\Nurul`, then copy and paste this command: `(gci -ad | ? name -match 'Desktop|Download' | gci -s).FullName `. You'll get a list of filenames with paths that should hep sort it out. What you see in **Explorer** may be misleading confusing because the `desktop.ini` files created for system folders can provide a display name different from the the actual directory name.

Answer (score 0):

By moving all files from your desktop to your downloads, all your desktop shortcuts are now also in the downloadssss folder, and you have to manually move them back.

You can find it by going to C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Downloadssss